# creating new table from multiple tables

Tags: mysql

Hi I'm trying to create a new lookup tables in which I need all columns that have date values from all the tables in a particular schema. When I'm trying to UNION the column, I am getting only the result of 1st select and seems like union is not working here. How can I get all these columns in my new table?
Here's my code for reference:

```
CREATE TABLE datetime_test AS (
SELECT col1, null as col2, null as col3 from table1
union all 
select col1, col2, col3 from table2
union all 
select col1, col2, null as col3 from table3 );
```

Answer (score 0):

> Error: Invalid operation: UNION types timestamp without time zone and integer cannot be matched

You must cast NULL in upper subquery of UNION to proper datatype. I.e. something like

```
SELECT col1, CAST(null AS DATETIME) as col2, CAST(null AS CHAR) as col3 from table1
UNION ALL
...
```

---

> I've changed my question a bit. I am getting the result from only 1st select i.e. columns from table1 in new table. Could you help me in understanding what is wrong here, or how can I get all columns? –
> Ros

`CREATE TABLE .. SELECT` needs in "scalar" query as a datasource. So use

```
CREATE TABLE datetime_test 
AS
SELECT *
FROM ( SELECT col1, null as col2, null as col3 from table1
       union all 
       select col1, col2, col3 from table2
       union all 
       select col1, col2, null as col3 from table3 ) AS total_data;
```

PS. I recommend you to define precise columns datatypes in CREATE TABLE part. Additionally this will make the casting for NULLs in UNION needless.

Comment: I've changed my question a bit. I am getting the result from only 1st select i.e. columns from table1 in new table. Could you help me in understanding what is wrong here, or how can I get all columns?

Comment: @Ros Answer updated.

Comment: Even after defining the datatypes nothing has changed, I am getting only the result of first select.

Comment: @Ros There are no miracles. If so then all another SELECTs does not produce rows.